# DTube url parser regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Please help to build regex for d.tube to extract `channel_id` and `video_id` from  url

Following urls possible

```
https://d.tube/v/channel_id/video_id
https://d.tube/#!/v/channel_id/video_id
https://emb.d.tube/#!/channel_id/video_id
```

Comment: The reason your question doesn't really elucidate what you want is because the examples / samples that are listed all include the **exact text-phrase** `channel_id` and the phrase `video_id`  I am not able to deduce what you are looking to do.  One version would be to **extract** the channel and video id's but another version would be to **verify** that the phrases (`channel_id` and `video_id`) are always present.  What are you looking to get from your reg-ex?

Comment: @RalphTorello, Sorry! I actually need to extract channel_id and video_id from url

Answer (score 1):

This should capture them two groups: `https:\/\/(?:emb)?\.?d.tube\/v?(?:#!)?\/?v?\/?(\w+)\/(\w+)`

It firstly matches `https` then the two forward slashes, which require the `\` escape character.

Optionally, it gets `emb`, then optionally a `.` then `d.tube`, optionally `/v`, optionally `#!`, optionally another `/`, optionally another `v` and `/` then two capture groups which take alpha numeric characters, split by a `/`.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted a comment to explain my point, but here are two (possible!) different versions of what you would want:

`https:\/\/(?:\w+\.)?d.tube\/.*?\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\n`

And then this would extract the `channel_id' and the`video_id` from the URL:  **NOTE:** This answer is ***partially* copied from** this stack-overflow answer: [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

```
var myString = myURL;
var myRegexp = /https:\/\/(?:\w+\.)?d.tube\/.*?\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\n/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log("Channel ID: " + match[0] + "\n" + "Video ID:" + match[1] + "\n");
```

Here is a screen-capture generated by http://regexr.com (pretty useful utiliity)
[image]

**While this solution here would verify that you had valid "d.tube" URL's**

```
https:\/\/(?:\w+\.)?d.tube\/.*?\/channel_id/video_id\n
var myString = myURL;
var myRegexp = /https:\/\/(?:\w+\.)?d.tube\/.*?\/channel_id/video_id\n/;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
var isMatch = match != null;
```